# Jhipster file throwing multiple errors after importing to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, ide, jhipster

I tried installing Jhipster IDE in STS 4 and Eclipse Java EE IDE but the marketplace say that the current version does not support jhipster IDE so I created a jhipster app from the terminal . It created fine but the problem is importing it into my IDEs both STS and Eclipse from the file menu option is making all the packages and class files throw multiple errors . This is a screen shot of the IDE after using the  "open projects from file system". What can I do to open it correctly and not let it throw these multiple errors ? [image]

Comment: What are the errors? A screenshot just showing lots of red Xs don't help us understand your problem much. Look in the Problems view for details about the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably opened the `src` subfolder instead of the project folder (assumed by the odd project name `src` shown in the screenshot).

In ***File > Open Projects from File System...*** choose the **directory that contains** the subfolder **`src`**, not the subfolder `src` itself.